# How to disable advanced label expressions for all layers using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, labeling

I have some MXDs with a large number of labeled layers. Recently I discovered that the Tiled Labels to Annotation tool didn't work with advanced Python label expressions (with FindLabel functions), so I had to simplify the expressions. But when changing the label expressions using Arcpy, the "Advanced" label expression checkbox remained checked.

I know I can't uncheck the checkboxes using Arcpy, but how can I disable the advanced expressions with ArcObjects? I'm completely new to ArcObjects, so can anyone give me some pointers how to start with this?

Comment: Tiled Labels to Annotation should work with Python label expressions. What results were you seeing? What version of ArcGIS are you using? This sounds like a question that should be asked at http://support.esri.com/

Comment: I'm using Desktop 10.4.1 and getting annotation features with null text strings. I actually spoke to the tool's author, Craig Williams from ESRI about this and he suggested to re-write the expressions in VBScript as a workaround. This certainly seems a bug to me but I'm hoping for a quick fix to this with ArcObjects, that's why I'm asking here :)

Comment: It's the [ILabelEngineLayerProperties2](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ILabelEngineLayerProperties2.htm) interface that you want. Something like [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/6164/48071) shows how to get from a layer object to the label expression.